# Question about PL/SQL and n tier architecture

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, computer-science

When it comes to a n tier architecture which tier would PL/SQL be executed on? mySQL is mostly databases so would it be executed on the data tier?

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language in the Oracle DBMS. It has nothing to do with MySQL. MySQL doesn't have a programming language built into the DBMS.

Comment: I fixed the tags, replacing [tag:mysql] with [tag:oracle].

Comment: it runs in the database.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner AFAIK, MySql has it's own dialect of SQL/PSM, they just don't have a special name for it like Oracle (PL/SQL) and SQL Server (T-SQL) do.

Comment: How would an in-database programming language run anywhere except the database?

Answer (score 4):

This is Oracle; PL/SQL runs in the database.